# How does Bitlocker encrypt a drive while it is being used?

Tags: aes, disk-encryption, bitlocker

By this I mean performing file transfers, downloads etc., I haven't read anywhere of this having an effect on how Bitlocker encrypts the drive. Also, how does Bitlocker handle the constant amount of data being read and written to the drive while it is encrypting it?

Comment: I'm not sure what level of detail you want to know. In general Bitlocker does transparent full disk encryption similar to many other solutions. This  means if an application writes data Bitlocker will encrypt the specific data block before it gets physically written to the disk. And if the application reads data the block will be read from disk, decrypted and the decrypted data handed to the application. Each block can be decrypted and encrypted independent from the others. Thus it does not matter if application constantly read and write data.

Comment: Bitlocker does encrypt the whole drive only once you convert a drive to being encrypted. After this is done only the changes are encrypted. The actual overhead of encryption depends on your system but according to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-frequently-asked-questions#bkmk-deploy) *"Generally it imposes a single-digit percentage performance overhead."*